# Move horizontal Victory Native bar chart to the left

Tags: css, react-native, victory-charts

In my React Native app I need to display some bar charts without an axis. However, all the bars are off to the right, as if there was an axis displayed which makes the screen look unbalanced. This is what my screen currently looks like:

[image]

I want to pull all those bar charts to the left, so that they are aligned with their labels. Can't seem to figure out how to do such a simple operation. I've tried playing around with the padding, domainPadding and all that to no avail. This is what my code currently looks like:

```js
const MyChart = () => (
  <VictoryGroup
    domainPadding={{ x: 30, y: 0 }}
    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
    domain={{ y: [0, 110] }}
  >
    <VictoryStack>
      {dataSet.map((data, index) => (
          <VictoryBar
            horizontal
            key={index}
            data={data}
            domainPadding={{ x: 0, y: 30 }}
            labels={d => 'Test Bar'}}
            labelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={-40} x={0} />}
          />
        )
      )}
    </VictoryStack>
  </VictoryGroup>
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My colleague figured this one out and I thought I may as well post the solution in case anyone stumbles upon this with the same issue.

The previously set padding was on the `VictoryGroup`, and you can't change it using the style prop and need to do so through the padding prop which I had overlooked in the docs.

So basically the lesson taken here was:

1- Was looking at the wrong place for the padding (my focus was on `VictoryBar`)

2- Do not use the `style` prop and use the `padding` prop.

Basically for the example given in the initial post, the solution for the problem would be the following:

```js
const MyChart = () => (
  <VictoryGroup
    domainPadding={{ x: 30, y: 0 }}
    theme={VictoryTheme.material}
    domain={{ y: [0, 110] }}
    padding={{ top: 30, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 0 }}
  >
    <VictoryStack>
      {dataSet.map((data, index) => (
          <VictoryBar
            horizontal
            key={index}
            data={data}
            domainPadding={{ x: 0, y: 30 }}
            labels={d => 'Test Bar'}}
            labelComponent={<VictoryLabel dy={-40} x={0} />}
          />
        )
      )}
    </VictoryStack>
  </VictoryGroup>
)
```

Comment: This response saved my day! I was spending hours on trying to find out how to move the bars to the left. THANK YOU! :-)